# Ajax rejecting JSON created by PHP with "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a page that makes an Ajax call, which retrieves, JSON encodes and returns data from a database. The page was working, but in the midst of making some changes, it's now failing. (Should note that I'm working with a test site and test database as I make the changes.)

The errorThrown parameter of the error case shows me "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data."

Here's the function with the Ajax call. (I've enhanced what's in the alerts for debugging purposes. I'll rip that back out once things are working.)

```
function acceptConfCode(){
    var emailAddr = $('#email').val();
    var confCode = $('#confcode').val();
    var fnargs = "ConfirmCode|'" + emailAddr + "'," + confCode ;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'retrievedata.php',
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        data: {"functionname":"confirmcode","arguments":fnargs},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (obj) {
            if (!obj.error) {
                $('#logininfo').hide();
                $('#emailrow').hide();
                $('#coderow').hide();
                $('#reviewactions').show();

                updateListOfActions(obj);
            }
            else {
                success = false;
                alert("The confirmation code you entered didn't match or has expired. Please try again. Type 1");
            }                   
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            success = false;
            alert("The confirmation code you entered didn't match or has expired. Please try again. Type 2. textStatus = " + textStatus + "; errorThrown = " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
};
```

The retrievedata PHP page is mostly a CASE statement. The relevant case is this (again with added debugging code):

```
        case 'confirmcode':
            if ($argcount <2) {
                $returnval = 'too few arguments';
            }
            else {
                   $returnval = confirmcode($argsarray[0], $argsarray[1]);
                   echo "Back from confirmcode\r\n";
                   var_dump($returnval);
            }
            break;
```

At the end of the page, it returns $returnval.

The key action is in the confirmcode function, which runs a MySQL SP to confirm that the user has a valid email and code, and then calls another function to retrieve the actual data. Here's confirmcode. As the commented out pieces show, I've checked results along the way and I am getting what I expect and it's getting JSON encoded; I've ran the encoded JSON back through JSON_decode() in testing to confirm it was decodable.

```
function confirmcode($spname, $params, $errorstring = 'Unable to send requested data') {
    $conn = connect2db();
    $query = "SELECT ".$spname."(".$params.") as result";
    //echo $query."\r\n";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $allresult = "unknown";

    if (!$result) {
        $errmessage = mysqli_error($conn);
        $allresult = $errmessage;
        $allresult = json_encode($allresult);
        //echo $errmessage;
        die( print_r( mysql_error(), true));
    }
    else {
        //echo "In else case\r\n";
        //retrieve list of action submissions
        $resultobj = mysqli_fetch_object($result); 
        if ($resultobj->result == 1) {
            //echo "In success subcase\r\n";
            $allresult = getsubmissions($conn);
            //echo "After getsubmissions\r\n";
            //print_r($allresult);
        }
        else {
            //echo "In failure subcase\r\n";
            $result = array('error'=>true);
            $allresult = $result;
        }

    //echo "Before JSON encode\r\n";
     $finalresult = json_encode($allresult);
    //echo "After JSON encode\r\n";
    //echo json_last_error_msg()."\r\n";
    //var_dump($finalresult);
     $allresult = $finalresult;
    return $allresult;

    }

}
```

Finally, here's getsubmissions, again with some debugging code:

```
function getsubmissions($conn) {
    echo "In getsubmissions\r\n";
    $query = "CALL GetSubmissions()";
    $submissions = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (!$submissions) {
        echo "In failure case\r\n";
        $errmessage = mysqli_error($conn);
        $allresult = $errmessage;
        $allresult = json_encode($allresult);
        echo $errmessage;
        die( print_r( mysql_error(), true));
    }
    else {
        echo "In success case\r\n";
        $rows = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($submissions)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        $allresult = $rows; //json_encode($rows);
    }

    //print_r( $allresult);
    return $allresult;
}
```

What's really weird is I have another page in the site that retrieves almost exactly the same data through an Ajax call with no problem. The one that works contains a few additional fields, and doesn't contain two date fields that are in this result.

In addition, the live version of the site retrieves exactly the same data as here, except from the live database rather than the test database, and it works. While this version of the code has some additional things in it, the only differences in the relevant portions are the debugging items. (That is, I've made changes, but not in the part I'm showing here.) That leads me to think this may be an issue with the test data rather than with the code, but then why does the other page work in the test site?

UPDATE: To try to see whether this is a data problem, I cut the test data way down so that it's only returning a couple of records. I grabbed the generated JSON and ran it through JSONLint.COM and it says it's valid.

UPDATE 2: With the reduced data set, here's the string that's returned from retrievedata.php to the Ajax call:

```
[{"ActionSource":"https:\/\/www.voterheads.com\/","ActionSourceName":"Wall-of-us","Title":"Sign up to get notified about local meetings","Description":"Sign up at www.voterheads.com to get notified about local meetings. When we did, using the free option, this is what happened: a page popped up with a list of municipality meetings in the zip code we entered. We clicked on one of the meetings, and presto! -- instant access to the date, time, location, and agenda of the meeting. Pretty awesome.","StartDate":null,"EndDate":null,"UrgencyDesc":"Anytime","UrgencyColor":"#00FF00","UrgOrder":"5","DurationDesc":"Ongoing","DurOrder":"6","CostDesc":"Free","CostOrder":"1","Issues":"Advocacy","Types":"Learn","States":"ALL","iID":"20"},{"ActionSource":"https:\/\/actionnetwork.org\/forms\/ctrl-alt-right-delete-newsletter-2","ActionSourceName":"Ctrl Alt Right Delete","Title":"Sign up to learn what the \"alt-right\" is up to","Description":"Understand how the right operates online. Sign up for a weekly newsletter.","StartDate":null,"EndDate":null,"UrgencyDesc":"Anytime","UrgencyColor":"#00FF00","UrgOrder":"5","DurationDesc":"An hour or less","DurOrder":"2","CostDesc":"Free","CostOrder":"1","Issues":"Advocacy","Types":"Learn","States":"ALL","iID":"25"}]
```

As noted above, JSONLint.COM says it's valid JSON.

Comment: Did you already look at the plain JSON your server is returning in your browsers development console? Obviously it's not what you are expecting. Propably `$argcount` is not `< 2`?

Comment: Your code is very confusing. Sometimes you call `json_encode()`, sometimes you don't. In one place you even re-encode something that's already encoded. You also have `echo "Back from confirmcode\r\n";` and `var_dump()`, which output non-JSON.

Comment: Yes, I've looked at the JSON that's returned and it looks fine.

Comment: @Barmar Good catch on the failure case of GetSubmissions encoding twice. But that's not the case that's running with this problem. Are you suggesting that the debugging code (echo and var_dump) changes the return value that's explicitly specified? I can certainly test with all the debugging code commented out to make sure it's not causing the problem.

Comment: The debugging code will definitely cause JSON parsing to fail, since it's printed along with the JSON.

Comment: @Barmar I just commented out every echo, print_r and var_dump in the path that's failing, and I'm still getting exactly the same error.

Comment: Is there any way to see exactly what string is being returned to the Ajax call before it attempts to parse? I've already confirmed that the call to json_encode on the PHP side is running successfully.

Comment: Use the Network tab of Developer Tools to see the whole response.

Comment: But with this error, no actual response page is getting generated. That's why I was dumping the string out from the PHP code.

Comment: The Network tab should show PHP's response to the XmlHttp request even if the browser then rejects it as invaliid.  Remember to check the preserve across navigations box in Chrome.

Comment: I'm using Firefox and I have the Persist Logs checkbox checked. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: The AJAX request should be getting a response even if it is a 500 error.  You can look at that response by viewing the details for that line of the network traffic list.

Comment: I was able to display the XHR object in the error case and it's a 200 response. The problem seems to come entirely in decoding the JSON.

Comment: You can look at the response body (in Chrome if you can't figure it out in Firefox) and compare that to a working response.

Comment: Without the debugging code, when this fails, the response body is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, though I'm just starting to understand why it works. On retrievedata.php, I uncommented:

```
echo $returnval;
```

just before the Return statement and it's working again. So I think the issue is that since retrievedata is a page, but not a function, the return statement didn't actually return anything. I needed code to actually return the JSON-encoded string.